# Example of a simplicial complex containing a free face with (at least) three vertices

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $\Delta$ be a simplicial complex, we say that a face $F$ of $\Delta$ is free provided there is a single vertex $v$ not contained in $F$ such that the face determined by the union of $F$ and $v$ is the unique facet (aka maximal face) both containing $F$ and $v$. For instance, the simplicial complex of three vertices given by facets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$ has two free faces, namely $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.
My question is the following one: can someone of you provide me an example of a simplicial complex containing a free face (namely, $F$), and such that $F$ has at least three vertices?

In an still ongoing joint work with another colleague, we have defined the notion of free pair; indeed, given a simplicial complex $\Delta$ and a couple of non-empty faces of it (namely, $F_1$ and $F_2$), we say that the pair $(F_1,F_2)$ is free if, on one hand, $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$, and, on the other hand, the face of $\Delta$ determined by the union of $F_1$ and $F_2$ is the unique facet containing both $F_1$ and $F_2$.
In this way, one can define the set $S$ of all possible free pairs of $\Delta$, and define a partial order on it (in a certain way), so $S$ becomes a poset with this partial order. It turns out that the maximal elements of $S$ are of the form $(F,v)$, where $F$ is a free face and $v$ is as above.

Keeping in mind the previous paragraph, I hope is clear that a response to my question implies that there are examples where $S$ is not only made up by maximal elements.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand your question. Let $\Delta$ be an $(n-1)$-simplex, i.e., the set of all subsets of an $n$-element set $V$. Let $F$ be any $(n-1)$-element subset of $V$. Then $F$ is a free face.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found myself an answer; just consider the simplicial complex $\Delta$ with facets $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{4,5\}$, $\{4,6\}$ and $\{5,6\}$; one can easily check that, for instance, $\{1,2,4\}$ is a free face of $\Delta$.